# Why do we give different names to parameters of the same method in different places in the programme?

Tags: java, parameters

I'm complete beginner to Java - sorry for the very basic question! This is a programme for guessing two random numbers.

```
    if (guessesOK(firstGuess,secondGuess,firstAnswer,secondAnswer)) {
        System.out.println("\tCorrect - well done!");
    } else {
        System.out.print("\tNo, the answers were ");
        System.out.println(firstAnswer + " and " + secondAnswer + ".");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static boolean guessesOK(int guessA, int guessB, int ans1, int ans2) {
    boolean okOneWay = (guessA == ans1 && guessB == ans2);
    boolean okOtherWay = (guessA == ans2 && guessB == ans1);
    return (okOneWay || okOtherWay);
}
```

My main question is why the parameters in the guessesOk method are different in each instance?

Any extra info you could share to explain a little bit about parameters would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're confused about. What do you mean "different in each instance"? You only call the method once.

Comment: Do you the mean difference in declaration `public static boolean guessesOK(int guessA, int guessB, int ans1, int ans2)` and in call `guessesOK(firstGuess,secondGuess,firstAnswer,secondAnswer))`?

Comment: Could not understand your question , please explain a little .

Comment: When you call a method, there is no requirement that the variable names you pass to the method should match the names of the variables used by the method.

Answer (score 1):

We don't give them different names, these are different *kinds* of parameters.

This line is a method declaration, it uses *formal* parameter names:

```
public static boolean guessesOK(int guessA, int guessB, int ans1, int ans2)
```

This line is an invocation, it uses *actual* parameter expressions (also known as arguments):

```
if (guessesOK(firstGuess, secondGuess, firstAnswer, secondAnswer))
```

Only formal parameters are required to have a name; actual parameters may be expressions other than variables, and have no name at all.

```
if (guessesOK("apple", "orange", 1, 25))
```

Comment: and the _actual parameters_ are `arguments`, right?

Comment: @pirho Right, parameter vs. argument is another popular way of distinguishing the two. I tend to call them formal vs. actual, the way I was taught in school back in mid-eighties.

Answer (score 0):

**Here your are calling your method by passing some values to it**

```
  if (guessesOK(firstGuess,secondGuess,firstAnswer,secondAnswer)) {
        System.out.println("\tCorrect - well done!");
    } else {
        System.out.print("\tNo, the answers were ");
        System.out.println(firstAnswer + " and " + secondAnswer + ".");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Here you are declaring and defining your method i.e..  it can take four int type values and also defining the logic here**

```
public static boolean guessesOK(int guessA, int guessB, int ans1, int ans2) {
    boolean okOneWay = (guessA == ans1 && guessB == ans2);
    boolean okOtherWay = (guessA == ans2 && guessB == ans1);
    return (okOneWay || okOtherWay);
}
```